# Locating origin of Macht Family from Bavaria;possibly Wunsiedel?

Tags: 19th-century, germany, bavaria

Family located from Germany to Norwich,CT area.  Johann and Nicolas worked in a textile mill.  Johann died in 1906 and his death certificate indicates parents names were Wolf and Barbara.  Have been unable to locate origin of Bavaria the family was from.  However, believe it may be Wunsiedel.

Names: Johann Macht born 1829, Nicolaus Macht his son, born 1859, Edward Macht his son, born around 1861.  Mother is unknown.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  It sounds like the record that you are seeking is either a baptism record or a marriage record for Johann (or his parents).

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! Can you tell us what other records you've gathered so far, in addition to Johann Macht's death certificate?  Do you have a timeline for the family in Connecticut?

Comment: I have the 1900, 1910, 1920, 1930 Census for Nicholas Macht. I also have his death certificate.  I have the 1900 Census for Johann Macht and his death certificate.